# Is it possible to write automation tests for nwjs app?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, node-webkit, nw.js

I am currently working on node-webkit based desktop app. I was searching for a way to do automation testing for this . But most of the automation tools required a server to start up but in my case i have on  but it runs in the chromium that comes by default. Is there a way to automate UI acceptance test for nwjs apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Take a look at the NW.js Wiki under [How to run node webkit's test cases](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-run-node-webkit%27s-test-cases)
2. You will need to [setup the chrome driver](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/chromedriver) in order to use selenium for example
3. Once you have those, check out Yaniv kessler's blog post on how to [Automate NW.js UI](http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2015/03/21/automate-nwjs-ui-testing/) testing using mocha.

Comment: To clarify, the article in bullet point #3 doesn't use chromedriver or selenium. It uses a whole different mechanism, called `chrome-remote-interface`